# jBPM 6.2.0 Send Velocity Template Email Notification on Task Creation

Tags: velocity, jbpm

Hi I am working on jBPM 6.2.0.

I need to send a Velocity Template Email Notification, upon Human Task creation. Do I need to write a separate Email Notiification Handler ? And how do I make sure it gets called in task Creation.

Please Note: Performance is an issue for us, we need to complete execution of each task in less than 1 sec.

Tech Stack:
jBPM 6.2.0.Final
Oracle 11g 
Java 1.7

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We have written a Custom Email notification utility and are calling it from TaskLifeCycleEventListener afterTaskAdded method. If there are any other good solution please let us know

Comment: Apparently EmailNotification service is tightly coupled in jBPM 6.2.0

We will need a custom Email notification for this.

Comment: How to get the user-list from the configed Task-Notification-Panel? each task has its email list....... 
                 
                 
 https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.3/userguide/images/Chapter-HumanTasks/human_task_editor_notification.png